# Problema al accesar a sistema dentro dentro de vdi "Cannot open log for source System. You may not have write access"

Tags: asp.net, login, wcf

actualmente estoy trabajando en un sistema en visual studio 2008, el cual al accesar con el usuario de windows **active directory** ( usuario que me dijeron que era para pasar por alto el **login** )

Me manda el error visto en pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy dentro de una vdi y el usuario **active directory**, se me dio de alta en otro equipo. mediante **remote desktop**

Alguien tiene una idea que pueda estar pasando. ya vi esta solución pero no tengo el archivo **"CustomSD"**  **https://forums.asp.net/t/1856635.aspx?Cannot+open+log+for+source+You+may+not+have+write+access+**

El sistema operativo en la vdi es **Windows 10 Enterprise**, sistema en **asp.net** con web services, wcf

Comment: Tenes acceso al servicio WCF y tu codigo para debugear?

Comment: asi es, este es el codigo

Comment: Que codigo? no mostras nada solo el error.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3vfY.png

Comment: en la imagen el subrayado azul es donde marca error

Comment: Context : tiene los datos del usuario, tomados de los datos de windows

Comment: Framework.Security.PUI , esta es una dll del cual se toma una clase para crear el objeto objSecurity

Answer (score 0):

Al fin se soluciono levantando la aplicación, elegir visual studio 2008 --> Ejecutar como administrador